# In Rails 3, respond_to and format.all works differently than Rails 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mime

the code

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render :json => @switches }
  format.xml { render :xml => @switches.to_xml }
  format.all { render :text => "only HTML, XML, and JSON format are supported at the moment." }
end
```

the above will work in Rails 2.2.2.  But in Rails 3, getting controller/index.html or index on the browser will both fall into the last line: "only HTML and JSON format are supported at the moment."

The only Rails doc I can find on this is

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds/ClassMethods.html#method-i-respond_to

which current only states:

```
respond_to :html, :xml, :json
```

but they need separate templates for json and xml, and can't handle the "only HTML and JSON format are supported at the moment" case.

Answer (score 44):

In rails3 you would write:

```
respond_with(@switches) do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render :json => @switches }
  format.xml  { render :xml  => @switches }
  format.all  { render :text => "only HTML, XML, and JSON format are supported at the moment." }
end
```

But this only works in correspondence with a `respond_to` block at the top of the file, detailing the expected formats. E.g.

```
respond_to :xml, :json, :html
```

Even in that case, if anybody for instance asks the `js` format, the `any` block is triggered.

You could also still use the `respond_to` alone, as follows:

```
@switches = ...
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {render :text => 'This is html'}
  format.xml  {render :xml  => @switches}
  format.json {render :json => @switches}
  format.all  {render :text => "Only HTML, JSON and XML are currently supported"}
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the to_xml call is superfluous. The default Rails 3 responder should call it automatically.

Comment: format.any has the same problem as format.all for me. is this possibly relevant: http://blogs.thewehners.net/josh/posts/354-obscure-rails-bug-respond_to-formatany

Comment: @dogenpunk: that is correct of course. I edited my answer to show that. I also added a pure `respond_to` example (and added clarification). @dreeves: well for me it just works, the blogpost you mention is ancient in Rails-terms :)

Comment: It was `format.any` and I edited it to `format.all` because `format.any` is something different, it will take parameters like `format.any(:html, :json)` for instance

Comment: Which rails version are you testing against, because this code worked.

Answer (score 3):

You may find it useful to watch this episode of railscasts, which illustrates the changes to controllers in Rails 3 and in particular the changes to the responder class (putting respond_to in the controller class itself and only using respond_with @object in the action):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. I believe you have to specify the "render" part for html explicitly or it will use the format.any.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :html => @switches }
  format.json { render :json => @switches }
  format.xml  { render :xml  => @switches }
  format.all  { render :text => "we only have html, json, and xml" }
end
```