# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Proper way to respond in HTML, JSON, or XML

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the correct way to have my Index() method return content based on the incoming accept/content-type headers.

I currently have an application I am trying to refactor that has an Index() method and a JsonData() method. The browser pulls this "index" page and then via Ajax requests the /jsondata URL. I would like to put both under Index() and change the response types depending on the incoming request. What is the correct way to do this under MVC 4?

Note: we are not using Web API.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this - you're combining two totally distinct concepts (returning a page or returning data) into the same name - it can only generate confusion. I would leave it the way you have it - have `Index` respond to `GET` requests and return a view, and have `JsonData` response to `POST` requests and return data - there's no reason to combine them.

Comment: Rails does this all the time. How is a HTML representation that different than a JSON or XML one as far as REST is concerned. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672111/in-rails-3-respond-to-and-format-all-works-differently-than-rails-2

Comment: Just my opinion - you're right that HTML is technically just data. I just find it makes more sense to me to keep UI separate from data as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

You have several options here.

First - differentiate your requests by their verbs, and have a convention, such as all `GET`s receive html, while all `POST`s receive json.  Controller will look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult IndexGet()
{
    return View();
}


[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult IndexPost()
{
    return Json();
}
```

And of course its a client-side matter to make a request with correct method. **Update** - verbs only won't be enough here - to keep one action name you should also make use of `ActionName` attribute. thanks to [Joe Enos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111266/joe-enos) for pointing that out.

Second - introduce a parameter. Say by default you are sending html, but if ajax call appends a parameter `isJson` - give it json response:

```
public ActionResult Index(bool? isJson)
{
    if (isJson.HasValue && isJson.Value)
    {
        return Json();
    }

    return View();
}
```

Third - differentiate request by the mechanism behind them. In your case it seems that all ajax calls, and only them, should be served by json. Then you can use `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return Json();
    }

    return View();
}
```

And of course it is possible to combine these methods - say send json response only to POST requests by ajax.

Comment: In your first example you've got conflicting methods - even though you've got different verb attributes on them, you still need to distinguish the two methods with parameters if you need two methods.

Comment: @JoeEnos, reckless mistake, thanks for remark. However approach is still doable with `ActionName` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

May try to resolve this with request AcceptTypes?

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/json"))
            {
                //
            }
            else 
            {

            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: This is a good point; but an additional parameter would allow to override the Accept header value or allows to provide the type if the Accept header can´t be send by the client. For instance if you do ajax requests using XDomainRequest...